# coding with visual studio on macbook pro (2018)

Tags: macos, visual-studio

I'm learning C and C++. In our college we must code and compile with Visual studio 2017, and I want to buy the MacBook Pro ('18).
Is there a good way to code with visual studio on MacBook Pro for standard uses of student?? Or is Mac not recommended in this case?

Comment: Last I checked Visual Studio for Mac doesn't support C or C++, only .NET languages. You could still install Windows using Bootcamp or in a VM though (to get a native VS 2017 running)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use visual studio on a mac (that is different from visual studio for mac) using Parallels or similar virtualization technology.

Comment: Don't forget the dual-boot option (using Bootcamp) - I personally used that one when I was studying

Comment: yes, I also (often) use dual boot, but that's sort of missing the point on a mac (not judging, just if I'd go that route I'd buy a windows laptop)

Comment: no catch, just some versions cost money, works great

Comment: There isnt even one software in mac, that allow coding and debugging in c and c++??

Comment: no, there are probably plenty of free options that are perfectly fine for a college student (I'd check vscode + plugins). but if you want visual studio (which is the Cadillac) you might need to spend a bit (i.e. $80 for parallels, free visual studio community or express)

Comment: The editor Atom is pretty cool and it has a plug in for C/C++. And its free.

Answer (score 0):

VS code has an extension that allows you to do coding and debugging using C and C++. Its called C/C++ and was developed by microsoft. It has been downloaded over 10 million times so it is pretty popular and has a large user community.